# Python many variable names

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

Let's say I have a `for` loop till the `range(50)` and in that `for` loop I want to create 50 variable names like `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, `v4` till `v50` and the value of those variables should be the number which is in range, so `v1` will be 0, `v2 = 1`, and `v50 = 49`.

I tried this way but it failed:

```
for i in range(50):
 v{i} = i

print(globals())  # We print all the variables
```

Comment: Try using dictionary {variable_name :  variable_value}, what are you trying to achieve maybe you don't even need so many variable!!

Comment: Ok so i guess its not possible i know it can be done with dictionaries

Comment: Use a collection. The duplicate question proposes a dictionary. But in your case a list is just fine. `my_values = list(range(50))`. The n'th value is at `my_values[n]`.

Comment: @BobMicheall well it is possible, but creating dozens of variables is considered bad style if you could just use some form of collection instead.

Comment: Yes a list comprehension will do the job i just wanted to know if python has a type of special way to do it

Comment: If it is possible can you see me how?

Comment: I just wanna know

Comment: or use globals()["variable_name"] = variable_value

Comment: ok let me try..

Comment: Yes it work thanks a lot: It worked `for i in range(50):`
    `globals()[f"v{i}"] = i` `print(v4)` i got 4 thanks again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373201/3620003

Comment: i guess i know why we should not use the globals() function to make a variable because if i say `globals()["1k"] = 8` and if i say print(globals()) it actually create a variable but we cant print() the variable normally we have to say print(globals()["1k"]) as if we print() it normally we get an error and the globals() is unsafe to use as it breaks the laws of creating variables because normally in python it is impossible to create a variable named 1k